# Drop table en MySQL usando PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Usando una base de datos `MySQL` y `PHP` he intentado crear una tabla, verificando anteriormente si la tabla existe, y si es así borrándola. El problema es que me reporta error tanto en la eliminación de la tabla como en su creación. He intentado cambiar la sintaxis de la consulta, pero tampoco me ha funcionado.

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$passwd = '';


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$passwd);

if(!$conn){ die("Conexión fallida<br>") . mysqli_connect_error(); }
else{ echo "Conexión correcta<br>"; }

$set_charset = $conn -> set_charset("UTF-8");

$sql = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Info";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) 
{ 
    echo "La tabla ha sido eliminada correctamente.<br>"; 
}
else
{ 
    echo "Error en la eliminación de la tabla.<br>" . mysqli_error($conn); 
}


$sql = "CREATE TABLE Info (
               name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
               country NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
               email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
               worksat VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);";

if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{ 
    echo "Tabla creada correctamente.<br>"; 
}
else
{ 
    echo "Error en la creación de la tabla.<br>";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Quita lo del charset / comprueba permisos

Comment: Que es eso de NVARCHAR ??? Solo me suena Varchar

Comment: Veo que tienes el servername, el username y la pass, pero y la base de datos a la quieres a puntar para crear y borrar la tabla?

Comment: Te falta declarar la variable hacia donde apunte a la base de datos. y declarar tu variable servername a $servername

Comment: NVARCHAR lo uso en SQLServer y pensaba que también estaba implementado en MySQL. ¿Dónde exactamente tendría que especificar a la base de datos que apunto?

Comment: Ahora apuntando a la base de datos de esta forma me sigue reportando error `servername = "localhost";
            $username = "root";
            $passwd = '';
            $dbname = "bd_entregable_nombredelalumno";
            
            
            $conn = new mysqli($servername,$username,$passwd,$dbname);`

Comment: Que error te reporta?

Comment: ¿Le diste permiso al usuario para eliminar o crear en la DB?

Comment: Me devolvía el mensaje de error que estaba controlando. El usuario Tenía derechos ya que era `root`. Finalmente la solución era que primero debía crearlo estando en otra base de datos por ejemplo `test`.